# Reach data in collectionview

Tags: ios, json, swift, variables, uicollectionview

I have downloaded some data from a JSON File and I now have it in a object that is especially made for this data. I now wanna reach that data in a collectionView when I click on it, do I have to make this data globally available for all functions and classes or is there a way to reach the data in the CollectionView without downloading the data from the server every time you click on the collectionView?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
var sliderArray  = [UISlider]()

sliderValueDidChange(data: ? index: indexPath.row slider: sliderArray)
}

func sliderValueDidChange(data: [class] slider:[UISlider]){
  data[index]        
       slider.minimumValue = data[index].value




}
```

So something like that but I mean how do I get the data into the collectionView without making it globally available for every other function?

Comment: "without downloading the data from the server " seems like you want to persist data somewhere like sqlite or core data?

Comment: i have a function that downloads the data that i call in ViewDidLoad but i need it in the collectionView to use it as slider values

Comment: Make a model class for your data , and then play with your data.

Comment: yea that's what i mean with data[class] this is a way to send my class that withholds my data into the function i need it in and i need to give the sliders the Data at the time when the user presses the collectionView

Comment: it is ok for me to make the variable global but it feels not like the best way to do it. So that's why i asked this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the data, you can store this as a variable (property) of your view controller.

The collection view delegate didSelectItemAt function would then access this field as you have done in the example above.

This property will only be accessible within the view controller (you can make it 'private' so that it cannot be used outside the view controller itself). By doing this, it won't be accessible to all functions and classes as you have said you wanted to avoid.

To avoid storing the data as a property of view controller, you would want to move it out to another class that the network (download code) and the collection view delegate have access to.